# Sort date time information

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, datetime

Help please. I see only DATA and TIME, but For me need more information: Admin - Add Commend its feeds on site.

```
<div id="D">
<div><div class="dateDiv">2015-12-11 02:45:12</div> Admin -  Add Comment</div>
<div><div class="dateDiv">2015-12-11 02:49:12</div> Admin -  Add Comment</div>
<div><div class="dateDiv">2015-12-11 02:50:12</div> User -  Add Comment</div>
<div><div class="dateDiv">2015-12-11 03:39:32</div> Moderator -  Add Comment</div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
<script>

var elems = $.makeArray($(".dateDiv"));
elems.sort(function(a, b) {
 return new Date( $(a).text() ) < new Date( $(b).text() );
});
$("#D").html(elems);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change your script to this:

```
var elems = $.makeArray($("#D").children());
elems.sort(function(a, b) {
 return new Date( $(a).find('.dateDiv').text() ) < new Date( $(b).find('.dateDiv').text() );
});
$("#D").html(elems);
```